# Why does this code not output anything onto the canvas in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, linear-search

In p5.js I'm trying to visualise a Linear Search Algorithm. I have an array of numbers and want to visualise them by drawing them as lines pointing upwards.

**When I put the forEach loop in the setup function, nothing appears. If I put it in draw function, I see the exact result that I'm looking for pop up for half a second and then dissapear...**
(The setup function is called when the program is run, and the draw loop is continuously called every frame) (The line function draws a line from the first x,y to the second x,y line(x,y x,y)

Here's the code:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let buffer = 0

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  
  numbers.forEach((number) => {
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(4);
    line(buffer, height, buffer, number * 50)
    buffer += 15
  });
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
}
```

Comment: setup is first function executed by p5, then draw is executed each frame, and you are basically clearing the canvas by setting the background to white. Execute background in setup before iterating numbers

Answer (score 0):

Think about the order that things happen in.

You said it yourself:

> The setup function is called when the program is run, and the draw loop is continuously called every frame

So with the code you have, the `setup` function runs once at the very beginning of your program, and then the `draw` function is called 60 times per second. The only thing you're doing inside the `draw` function is drawing a background, which removes what you drew in the `setup` function. Try removing the call to `background(255)` to see what I mean.

Then when you move your code into the `draw` function, I'll offer this hint: What is the value of the `buffer` variable each frame? You might use some `console.log()` statements to answer that.